# How can I get the URL of a Pages List with REST API?

Tags: 2013, list, rest

My question is very simple. I would like to display the recent top 10 news with the REST API in Sharepoint 2013. I'm using the following query:

`http://my-server/my-news/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/items?$select=Id,Name,Title,Comments&$orderby=ArticleStartDate%20desc&$top=10&$filter=Title+ne+'Home'`

Now I would like to select the link to the news page. But as far as I know, there is no property that I can get that would give me the URL of the page.

Anyone knows a way, via the REST query, to get the URL? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried getting the column 'FileRef'?

If not can you construct the URL using the Name?

Comment: Wonderful, FileRef is working. Thank you so much! (Might want to edit your post from FieldRef to FileRef)

Comment: Here is the link for FileRef: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.fileref.aspx

Answer (score 5):

`FileRef` field in `$select` query option will return page url.

For example, the query:

```
https://fabrikam.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items?$top=1&$select=Id,Title,FileRef
```

will return:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="https://fabrikam.sharepoint.com/_api/" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" 
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" 
    xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" 
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <id>07244208-09fa-4014-bd1f-785a73b8d4a1</id>
    <title />
    <updated>2014-01-23T21:14:58Z</updated>
    <entry m:etag="&quot;5&quot;">
        <id>78183075-e864-4e76-8efb-38bf6e2190f9</id>
        <category term="SP.Data.PagesItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'a976fb47-81fa-47ae-a487-7d6d656a54ce')/Items(1)" />
        <title />
        <updated>2014-01-23T21:14:58Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Id>
                <d:Title>Home</d:Title>
                <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:ID>
                <d:FileRef>/Pages/default.aspx</d:FileRef>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <link rel="next" href="https://fabrikam.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items?%24skiptoken=Paged%3dTRUE%26p_SortBehavior%3d0%26p_ID%3d1&amp;%24top=1&amp;%24select=Id%2cTitle%2cFileRef" />
</feed>
```